# Postgres query : using previous dynamically created colum value in next

Tags: postgresql, recursion, case, lag, coalesce

I'm trying to implement what I have in code as a postgres query.
The following example isn't exactly what we're trying to do but I hope it shows how I'm trying to use the value from a previously calculated row in the next.

A sample table to help me demonstrate what I'm trying to do :

```
test=# select * from test ;
 id | field1 | field2 | field3 | score
----+--------+--------+--------+-------
  1 |      1 |      3 |      2 |  1.25
  2 |      1 |     -1 |      1 |
  3 |      2 |      1 |      5 |
  4 |      3 |     -2 |      4 |
```

Here's the query in progress:

```
select id,
    coalesce (
            score,
            case when lag_field3 = 2 then 0.25*(3*field1+field2) end
    ) as new_score
from (
    select id, field1, field2, field3, score,
    lag (field3)  over (order by id) as lag_field3
    from test
) inner1 ;
```

Which returns what I want so far ...

```
 id | new_score
----+-----------
  1 |      1.25
  2 |       0.5
  3 |
  4 |
```

The next iteration of the query:

```
select id,
    coalesce (
            score,
            case when lag_field3 = 2 then 0.25*(3*field1+field2) end,
            case when field1 = 2 then 0.75 * lag (new_score) end
    ) as new_score
from (
select id, field1, field2, field3, score,
    lag (field3)  over (order by id) as lag_field3
from test
) inner1 ;
```

The difference is this :

```
case when field1 = 2 then 0.75 * lag (new_score) end
```

I know and understand why this won't work.

I've aliased the calculated field as new_score and when field1 = 2, I want 0.75 * the previous rows new_score value.
I understand that new_score is an alias and can't be used.

Is there some way I can accomplish this? I could try to copy that expression, wrap a lag around it, alias that as something else and try to work with that but that would get very messy.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please, provide the disred output of the final query and the query needed to create the table.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres lets you use windows in `CASE` statements. Probably you were missing the `OVER (ORDER BY id)` part. You can also define different windows but you can't use windows in conjunction with `GROUP BY`. Also, it won't let you use annidate windows, so you have to write down some subqueries or CTEs.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(tmp_score,
                    CASE 
                        WHEN field1 = 2 
                            THEN 0.75 * LAG(tmp_score) OVER (ORDER BY id) 
                            -- missing ELSE statement here
                    END
           ) AS new_score
FROM (
    SELECT id, field1,
        COALESCE (
                score,
                CASE 
                    WHEN LAG(field3) OVER (ORDER BY id) = 2 
                    THEN 0.25*(3*field1+field2) 
                END
        ) AS tmp_score
    FROM test
) inner1
```

The code to create and populate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id int,
    field1 int,
    field2 int,
    field3 int,
    score numeric
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 1, 3, 2, 1.25),
(2, 1, -1, 1, NULL),
(3, 2, 1, 5, NULL),
(4, 3, -2, 4, NULL);
```

The query returns this output:

```
 id | new_score 
----+-----------
  1 |      1.25
  2 |      0.50
  3 |    0.3750
  4 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that but that didn't work...the issue is that 'new_score' is an alias :

    ERROR:  column "new_score" does not exist
    LINE 5:             CASE WHEN field1 = 2 THEN 0.75 * LAG(new_score) ...

Comment: Try now. Btw, it's not very clear what you're trying to do. The second lag you added shoul be part of the coalesce?

Comment: It shouldn't give you any syntax error.. please, refresh the browser page.

Comment: It's giving me this now : ERROR:  window function calls cannot be nested
LINE 5:                 CASE WHEN LAG(field3) OVER w = 2 THEN 0.25*(... Will try to explain better what I'm trying to do in my next comment

Comment: Try again please. Probably I better understood your needs, but you should introduce a `ELSE` statement in the last `COALESCE` to handle the last `NULL` value returned by the query.

Comment: Thanks pietrop, appreciate your time. Latest query does return but don't think it works for me. To explain better .. the 'new_score' value is initially the value of score and for subsequent rows, it's value can either depend on the previous value (kind of iterative/recursive) or can be something completely different ( 3 scenarios).  Let's see if this explains the problem, let's say for odd values of id, i wanted the new_score value to be the same as id but for even values I wanted the previous value squared + 1. i.e 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:10. Question is more or less how can i reference prev value?

Comment: @David The query I wrote down does exactly what you intended to do in your original question, but as far as I understand, your algorithm doesn't provide the expected results. In order to check if a number is odd you need to use the module operator. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html . For example, `4 % 2` returns `0` (`4` is a even number) while `5 % 2` returns `1` (`5` is a odd number). Try to better reformulate your original question with the expected output by editing it.